# С++ OpenCV - cv::dft - Without computing negative frequency terms

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, dft

If I execute the following code:

```
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> inArr { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> outArr;
    cv::dft(inArr, outArr);
```

Then the outArr array will contain:

```
[ 
  1.+0.j,
 -0.80901699+0.58778525i,
  0.30901699-0.95105652i,
  0.30901699+0.95105652i,
 -0.80901699-0.58778525i
]
```

Although I need a result without calculating negative frequency terms, i.e. such:

```
[ 
 1.+0.j,
-0.80901699+0.58778525i,
 0.30901699-0.95105652i
]
```

How can I do this ?

P.S. numpy.fft.rfft() works similarly in python.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gadd6cf9baf2b8b704a11b5f04aaf4f39d)? `cv::dft` can take a real-valued array as input, in which case it returns a CCS packed transform (which has no redundant information).

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I asked because I hoped that they would answer me with an algorithm, or some OpenCV function that I might not know about, to solve my problem. Directly with complex numbers.

Comment: If you're willing to use a different library, then yes you can do this. But I don't think you can do it with OpenCV. OpenCV is very specific for solving Computer Vision problems, and quickly shows limitations if you try to apply it to other problems. I would recommend [PocketFFT](https://gitlab.mpcdf.mpg.de/mtr/pocketfft/-/tree/cpp) (see `r2r_fftpack()`, it's also significantly faster than OpenCV's DFT implementation).

Comment: @CrisLuengo - `r2r_fftpack()` accepts and returns an array with primitive numbers and can miss the imag zero, just like `cv::dt`, and `c2c()` when passing an array with complex numbers returns an array with the calculation of negative frequency terms, so that unfortunately does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer if anyone needs it.
The solution is in the FFTW library.
But it is distributed under the "GNU General Public License".

```
std::vector<double> inArr{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
std::vector<std::complex<double> > outArr(inArr.size());
fftw_execute(fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(inArr.size(), inArr.data(), (fftw_complex *)outArr.data(), FFTW_ESTIMATE));
```

Comment: You can do exactly the same with PocketFFT, which I suggested to you two days ago. PocketFFT has a permissive license and is competitive in speed with FFTW.